# Copy specific file types from one host to another

Tags: bash, ssh, scp

I'm creating a bash script that automatically copies C source and header files from a particular directory in another host to the directory I'm in on the current host.

It currently generates this command:
ssh host2 "cd dir1/dir2 && find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*.(c|h)' | tar -T - -c -f -" | tar xf -

The problem is I get this error:
"tar: This does not look like a tar archive"

This error is output by the final tar (tar xf -) because for some reason the tar file that gets piped is corrupt.

If I do it instead using a combination of ssh, tar and scp it works fine, but that requires me to enter my password (for host2) twice (once for the ssh and once for the scp).  I could enter the password as an argument to the script, but I don't want it to appear in my bash history.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use `rsync` to do this job instead?  It supports `--filter` which fits your needs exactly.  Here's a sample:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1240150

Comment: Thanks.  I managed to do it with:
rsync --include=*.c --include=*.h --exclude=* $SOURCE_HOST:$PATH/* .

Comment: It's not working for me: **rsync -avz --include=*.h --exclude=* SRC_DIR DST_DIR** copies the .h files from SRC_DIR but NOT RECURSIVELY. Applying the **--recursive** option does not help :(

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using `rsync` with appropriate `--include` and `--exclude` flags? `rsync` can copy over `ssh`, and you should be able to copy the entire tree (or an subset) with a single command.

Also, if your only concern is having to type in your password you could also just try using authorized keys (and possibly ssh-agent) so you don't need to type in your password to access the other host.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to do it with: rsync --include=*.c --include=*.h --exclude=* $SOURCE_HOST:$PATH/* .